# How to make container wait for other container in Docker Compose

Tags: docker, deployment, configuration, containers, docker-compose

I'm following [this](https://blog.philipphauer.de/tutorial-continuous-delivery-with-docker-jenkins/) tutorial and try to start the infrastructure using Docker Compose instead of shell scripts calling docker client. Everything works fine, except gitlab container is started before gitlab-postgreql and gitlab-redis, thus failing, as it expects those services be already running.

I tried to use *depends_on* attributes, but it didn't solve the problem. As far as I know, it doesn't help, if other containers are faster to start. After a research I figured out, Docker Compose doesn't provide out-of-the-box solution to control container creation order.

How can this be? I can't believe such a *fundamental* feature have left unimplemented. Seems like Docker is stumbling on it's own cleverness and forgets the basics. Now, how do I control the container creation order without some crazy support scripts (which would make whole configuration more cluttered than just using scripts / docker client for everything in the first place)

Here is the docker-compose.yml as it is

```
version: '2'
services:

  gitlab-postgresql:
    image: sameersbn/postgresql:9.4-3
    volumes:
      - /srv/docker/gitlab/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
    environment:
      - DB_NAME=gitlabhq_production
      - DB_USER=gitlab
      - DB_PASS=password

  gitlab-redis:
    image: sameersbn/redis:latest
    volumes:
      - /srv/docker/gitlab/redis:/var/lib/redis
    depends_on:
      - "gitlab-postgresql"

  gitlab:
    image: sameersbn/gitlab:7.14.3
    volumes:
      - /srv/docker/gitlab/gitlab:/home/git/data
    ports:
      - "2222:22"
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      - GITLAB_PORT=8080
      - GITLAB_SSH_PORT=2222
    depends_on:
      - gitlab-postgresql
      - gitlab-redis

  registry:
    image: registry:2
    volumes:
      - /srv/docker/registry/data:/var/lib/registry
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - "gitlab"

  jenkins:
    image: jenkins:1.609.3
    volumes:
      - /srv/docker/jenkins/home:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/bin/docker:/bin/docker
      - /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapparmor.so.1.1.0:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapparmor.so.1
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
      - "50000:50000"
    user: root
    depends_on:
      - "registry"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> gitlab container is started before gitlab-postgreql and gitlab-redis,

You are using `depends_on` which wait until docker container status is not "up", but every service or program within this container can be "not finished" or in statuses like "run" or "up".

Check [Controlling startup order in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) I think it is exactly what you need.

> Use a tool such as wait-for-it or dockerize. These are small wrapper
> scripts which you can include in your application’s image and will
> poll a given host and port until it’s accepting TCP connections.
> Supposing your application’s image has a CMD set in its Dockerfile,
> you can wrap it by setting the entrypoint in docker-compose.yml:

So you will need entrypoint that will wait after postgres port will be available and postgres in running status.
In docker-compose you will need for example
`entrypoint: ./wait-for-it.sh db:5432`

and in the script you will check every second whether postgres is running - docker container will be blocked until postgres is unavailable.

Like in documentation:

```
until psql -h "$host" -U "postgres" -c '\l'; do
  >&2 echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done
```

Comment: This is ridiculous. Well, better just wait compose gets more mature, than wasting time learning these hacks to learn a broken tool. Thanks for the answer anyway, it was a funny joke.

Comment: @TuomasToivonen Well, this problem is not so easy to solve in the area of distributed system and as they advised the best way is to perform check in application layer. But I agree it should be provided by compose itself, but right now this "workaround" is official suggestion by **docker documentation**. Anyway [this PULL REQUEST - 374](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/374) for this feature (opened since 2014).

Comment: Excellent answer I didn't know it was part of the docker-compose documentation. This question is asked many times with different variables. This link easies the task to answer these kind of questions

Answer (score 2):

You can use `depends_on` with `healthcheck` if using compose v2.1+ (but not 3+ as it dropped `condition` https://github.com/peter-evans/docker-compose-healthcheck/issues/3)

[Example on GitHub](https://github.com/peter-evans/docker-compose-healthcheck/blob/master/docker-compose.yml)

Example, in a database container:

```
healthcheck:
  test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres"]
  interval: 30s
  timeout: 30s
  retries: 3
```

Project that depends on database:

```
depends_on:
  kong-database:
    condition: service_healthy
```